# Функция выравнивания строки на JavaScript

Tags: javascript

*Столкнулась с такой задачей, помогите пожалуйста!!*

Написать функцию, входными параметрами которой являются: строка и целое число `k`.
Функция должна вернуть строку длиной `k`, представляющей собой выравнивание первой строки  до длины `k`.
Выравнивание строки заключается в том, что между её отдельными *словами* дополнительно вносятся пробелы так, чтобы длина строки стала равной заданной длине, а последнее *слово* строки сдвинулось к её правому краю.

**При решении, не использовать готовые строковые функции**

Входные данные:

- строка - любой набор символов, например: `the sun is shining`;
- натуральное число, например: `21`.

*Словом*, в этом случае, можно считать отрезок строки между двумя пробелами/после пробела (слово1 `the`, слово2 `sun` и т.д.)

Выходные данные - строка с нужным количеством пробелов: `the__sun__is__shining`.
Символ `_`, в данном случае, заменяет пробел.

У меня есть набросок функции:

```js
function al(str,k){
        let sc='';
        let res='';
        for(let i=0; i<=k-str.length; i++){
            res+=sc
        }
        res+=str;
    }
```

Comment: Что Вы уже сделали?

Comment: У меня имеется набросок функции, я его добавила выше

Comment: Это бессмыслица, а не "набросок функции". Что Вы уже сделали, чтобы решить поставленную задачу?

Comment: На данный момент у меня имеется только эта функция, я только начинаю работу с JS и поэтому обратилась за помощью. Извините, если что-то не так

Comment: приведи примеры входных и выходных данных. А так же определение, что является словом

Comment: Входные данные: строка-любой набор символов , например "the sun is shining", натуральное число, например 21. Словом, скорей всего в этом случае можно считать отрезок строки между двумя пробелами/после пробела(слово1 the; слово2 sun и т.д ) Выходные данные -  строка с нужным кол-вом пробелов: "the  sun  is  shining"

Comment: "примеры *входных* и *выходных* данных" - ??

Comment: Выходные данные - строка с нужным кол-вом пробелов: "the__sun__is__shining" *'_'  в данном случае заменяет пробел

Comment: Под описание вашей задачи можно тупо добавить нужное количество пробелов перед последним словом, т.к. какое-то правило распределения пробелов не оговаривается. Т.е. можно в вашем примере сделать так `"the_sun_is____shining"`.

Comment: Т.е. задача в реализации т.н. выравнивания по ширине?

Comment: Да, нужно выровнять строку по ширине

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function al(n, k) {
let x = 0
let p = ' '
t = n.split('')

for (let i = 0; i < k + 1; i++) {
    if (t.length == k) {
        n = t.join('')
        return n
    }

    if (t[i] == p) {
        t.splice(i + 1, 0, p)
        i = i + (1 + x)
    }

    if (i == k) {
        i = 0
        x++
    }
}
```

}
console.log(al('the sun is shining', 50))

Comment: спасибо большое!!))